# Word - Is it possible to change easily all links' source in a document?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office, ms-word

I have 5 **Word template linked to an Excel file** to automatically generate new pre-formated reports.

As I am working on improving it, I have created **copies that will replace the old** version once I'm done. And in each template, I have approximately 70 links, so almost **350 links in total**.

My question is :

> Is there a way to change easily the source file for multiple links?

Solutions **with or without code** are welcome!

[image: Links in Word file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible? **Yes**

How? A [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=word+vba+change+link+source&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) reveals multiple options with lots of code to copy/paste.

Comment: My bad, I was in a hurry because I'm working on 5 projects at a time and my boss was on my heels for the others. I didn't took time to properly Google it... Shame on me! And still thank you because the link is awesome!

Comment: Hey, sorry, that came across really rough. I guess, at the time, it was intended that way, _but it shouldn't have been_. Glad the search link was helpful. I've found a general `<application> VBA <issue>` Google search _frequently_ finds what I need, often with a SO link within the top 5, and usually my first choice!

Comment: Don't worry mate, I could have done the same (and probably worse, as I get mad after every question : "I need to copy ...").
I just felt a bit trolled, but I do love that, so thanks for your help and the `<application> VBA <issue>` seems to be pretty efficient!